# jQuery .ajax() POST Request throws 405 (Method Not Allowed) on RESTful WCF

Tags: jquery, web-services, rest, post, wcf-rest

I am sending a post request to a RESTFUL WCF service application.  I am able to successfully send a `POST` request through Fiddler.

However when I do this through the jQuery Ajax method the function returns the following to the Chrome Developer Console:

```
OPTIONS http://www.example.com/testservice/service1.svc/GetData 405 (Method Not Allowed) jquery.min.js:6
```

But then a second after logs:

```
Object {d: "You entered 10"} testpost.html:16
```

What this tells me is that jQuery is sending a **`OPTIONS`** request, which fails, and then sending a `POST` request which returns the expected data.

My jQuery Code:

```
$.ajax() {        
type: "POST", //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb 
    url: "http://www.example.com/testservice/service1.svc/GetData", // Location of the service      
    data: '{"value":"10"}', //Data sent to server
    contentType:"application/json",
    dataType: "json", //Expected data format from server    
    processdata: false,
    success: function (msg) {//On Successfull service call   
        console.log(msg);
    },
    error: function (xhr) { console.log(xhr.responseText); } // When Service call fails             
});
```

I am using jQuery version 2.0.2.

Any help on why this error is occurring would be a great help.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

**Your code is actually attempting to make a [Cross-domain (CORS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) request**, not an ordinary `POST`.

That is: Modern browsers will only allow Ajax calls to services in the **same domain** as the HTML page.

**Example:** A page in `http://www.example.com/myPage.html` can only directly request services that are in `http://www.example.com`, like `http://www.example.com/testservice/etc`. If the service is in other domain, the browser won't make the direct call (as you'd expect). Instead, it will try to make a CORS request.

To put it shortly, to perform a CORS request, your browser:

- Will first send an `OPTION` request to the target URL
- And then **only if** the server response to that `OPTION` contains the [adequate headers (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is one of them)](http://enable-cors.org/server.html) to allow the CORS request, the browse will perform the call (almost exactly the way it would if the HTML page was at the same domain).

  - If the expected headers don't come, the browser simply gives up (like it did to you).

**How to solve it?** The simplest way is to enable CORS (enable the necessary headers) on the server.

If you don't have server-side access to it, you can mirror the web service from somewhere else, and then enable CORS there.

Comment: Okay it makes sense now. Thank you very much.

Comment: would't `jsonp` also do the job - as long as it's supported by the server?

Comment: @Sumit If all you do is `GET`, then **JSONP** could be an option. Still, JSONP is more of a workaround than a solution, since you can do very limited things with it. You cant do `POST`s (or `PUT`s etc.) through JSONP.

Answer (score 6):

You must add this code in **global.aspx**:

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create the required headers in a filter too.

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns="/rest/*")
public class AllowAccessFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest sRequest, ServletResponse sResponse, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("in AllowAccessFilter.doFilter");
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)sRequest;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)sResponse;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type"); 
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This Worked for me

In **Web.config** add below script

```html
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" >
    <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
  </modules>
  <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script">
    <remove name="WebDAV" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
    <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />

    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*."
         verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"
         type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
         preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
 </system.webServer>
```

Also in **RouteConfig.cs**

Change

settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;

To

settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;

Hope it helps you or some one :)

Answer (score 0):

For same error code i had quite different reason, I'm sharing here to help

I had web api action like below

```
public IHttpActionResult GetBooks (int id)
```

I changed the method to accept two parameters category and author so i changed the parameters as below, i also put the attribute [Httppost]

```
public IHttpActionResult GetBooks (int category, int author)
```

I also changed ajax options like below and at this point i start getting error 405 method not allowed

```
var options = {
    url: '/api/books/GetBooks',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    traditional: true, 
    data: {
        category: 1,
        author: 15
    }
}
```

When i created class for web api action parameters like below error was gone

```
public class BookParam
{
    public int Category { get; set; }
    public int Author { get; set; }
}
public IHttpActionResult GetBooks (BookParam param)
```

Answer (score 0):

for VScode users - are you using the **live-server** through vs code? access normally :)

jQuery .ajax()
does not work in -

```
http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html
```

it works in!! -

```
http://192.168.29.10/index.php
```