# jQuery .ajax() 405 (Method Not Allowed) / Cross Domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, wcf

I have seen so many questions on SO about this, but I can't find what is missing in my code.

I'm implementing [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/index.html) cause I don't want to use `JSONP`.

I know this is a [preflighted request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) and I think I'm adding the correct `headers`.

The error is that the website doesn't seem to like my `WCF` and every time I do a request, an `OPTION` method called is made even tho I have the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header.

I just want to make a `POST` call to my `WCF` with a `contentType: "application/json",`

The `WCF` is self hosted, the web application is on `IIS 7.5`.

---

**What Chrome shows:**

[image]

---

**What fiddler shows**
[image]

---

**Contract**

```
<OperationContract()>
<WebInvoke(Method:="POST",
           RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json,
           ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json,
           BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)>
<FaultContract(GetType(ServiceFault))>
Function LookUpPerson(person As Person) _
                     As List(Of Person)
```

---

**app.config**

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP"
             crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service name="Project.Services.Person">  
    <endpoint address="ws"  binding="wsHttpBinding"     contract="Project.Services.Interfaces.IPublic" />   
    <endpoint address=""    binding="webHttpBinding"    contract="Project.Services.Interfaces.IPublic"
              behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>

<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="customHeaders"
         type="Project.Services.Utilities.EnableCrossOriginResourceSharingBehavior, Project.Services, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"/>
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>

<endpointBehaviors>
  <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
    <webHttp/>
    <customHeaders />
  </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

---

**javascript**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://192.168.0.61:8282/Project.Services.Person/LookUpPerson",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "json",
    data: { person: JSON.stringify(person) },
    success: function (data) {
        // doing something
    },
    error: function (error) {
        // doing something
    }
});
```

---

On the WCF I have the following handlers, according to http://enable-cors.org/server_wcf.html

```
Public Class CustomHeaderMessageInspector
        Implements IDispatchMessageInspector

        Private requiredHeaders As Dictionary(Of String, String)
        Public Sub New(headers As Dictionary(Of String, String))
            requiredHeaders = If(headers, New Dictionary(Of String, String)())
        End Sub

        Public Function AfterReceiveRequest(ByRef request As System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message,
                                            channel As System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel,
                                            instanceContext As System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext) _
                                        As Object _
                                        Implements System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest
            Return Nothing
        End Function

        Public Sub BeforeSendReply(ByRef reply As System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message,
                                   correlationState As Object) _
                               Implements System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IDispatchMessageInspector.BeforeSendReply
            Dim httpHeader = TryCast(reply.Properties("httpResponse"), HttpResponseMessageProperty)
            For Each item In requiredHeaders
                httpHeader.Headers.Add(item.Key, item.Value)
            Next
        End Sub

    End Class
```

---

**And**

```
Public Class EnableCrossOriginResourceSharingBehavior
        Inherits BehaviorExtensionElement
        Implements IEndpointBehavior

        Public Sub AddBindingParameters(endpoint As ServiceEndpoint, bindingParameters As System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection) _
                                        Implements System.ServiceModel.Description.IEndpointBehavior.AddBindingParameters

        End Sub

        Public Sub ApplyClientBehavior(endpoint As ServiceEndpoint, clientRuntime As System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime) _
                                         Implements System.ServiceModel.Description.IEndpointBehavior.ApplyClientBehavior

        End Sub

        Public Sub ApplyDispatchBehavior(endpoint As ServiceEndpoint, endpointDispatcher As System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.EndpointDispatcher) _
                                        Implements System.ServiceModel.Description.IEndpointBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior
            Dim requiredHeaders = New Dictionary(Of String, String)()

            requiredHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            requiredHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS")
            requiredHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Content-Type, Accept")
            requiredHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000")

            endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(New CustomHeaderMessageInspector(requiredHeaders))
        End Sub

        Public Sub Validate(endpoint As ServiceEndpoint) _
            Implements System.ServiceModel.Description.IEndpointBehavior.Validate

        End Sub

        Public Overrides ReadOnly Property BehaviorType() As Type
            Get
                Return GetType(EnableCrossOriginResourceSharingBehavior)
            End Get
        End Property

        Protected Overrides Function CreateBehavior() As Object
            Return New EnableCrossOriginResourceSharingBehavior()
        End Function

    End Class
```

Sorry for the long post, I wanted to be specific.

Thanks in advance.

---

**UPDATE**

If I use `contentType: "text/plain"` I get the error on the chrome console:

> POST `http://192.168.0.61:8282/Project.Services.Person/LookUpPerson` 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Could'nt find anything good to help but found [this](http://www.israelaece.com/post/Introducao-ao-CORS.aspx) post about CORS where the data sent in the `OPTIONS` is different than your. Maybe it give you a clue but no sure if those are synonyms for the same thing you wrote.

Comment: @VitorCanova thanks, gonna check it out.

Comment: I haven't done this with WCF but I have with WebAPI. When I got 400 Bad Request it was because I was throwing an exception inside my method on the server. Are you able to attach a debugger to the WCF code and see the request and step through?

Comment: @ErikNoren Yes, I have a breakpoint on the method, but its not being triggered

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333013/jquery-ajax-post-request-throws-405-method-not-allowed-on-restful-wcf

Comment: @DeepakMishra already seen it. Doesn't help much, it says `How to solve it? The simplest way is to enable CORS`, I have done it, but it's still not working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same issue and this fixed it for me.

Change

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "Post")]
```

to

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "*")]
```

because although you accept `POST`, modern browsers will always send `OPTIONS`.

Comment: With `"*"` It allows me to reach the server, but I'm getting a new error with a bad request. Thanks tho

Comment: Once you get this far (correctly handling CORS requests etc), you still need one more item.  Some code like
    `if (WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Method == "OPTIONS")
    return null;`
in the service method so that it will not abort (generate a 400 response) during the pre-flight call.