# How can I get this JSON from jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json

How could I get this JSON from jQuery and iterate it? I'm trying this:

```
$.post( 'https://ubuntu-mate.org/apps.json', function( data ) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

But I'm getting a `405 Not Allowed` error. But if you visit from your browser you can access it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `$.get()`. `Post` is not allowed, hence the 405 error. Why are you trying to post there anyway if you say you're trying to GET this json?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17333053/1190388

Comment: Looks like a CORS issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery .ajax() POST Request throws 405 (Method Not Allowed) on RESTful WCF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333013/jquery-ajax-post-request-throws-405-method-not-allowed-on-restful-wcf)

Comment: @Zealander .get() is returning a 200 error and Response empty.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://ubuntu-mate.org/apps.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @costales CORS problem. I'm not familiar with Ubuntu Mate API, but it looks like you need to get an API key from them to authenticate your calls.