# $.ajax call in content script throwing 405 error

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I'm expecting the following piece of code to execute the Ajax call. However, I see a 405 error which says

> The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.

If I use **type = 'json'** I get

> The requested resource does not support http method 'JSON'.

*Here is the relevant portion of my content script code*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var imgSrcArr = [];
            $('img').each(function(e) {
                var s = this.src;
                imgSrcArr.push(s);

                $.ajaxSetup({cache: false});

                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append("apikey", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"); 
                formData.append("isOverlayRequired", false);
                formData.append("url", s);              
                //console.log(formData);

                //console.log($.support.cors);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "https://api.ocr.space/parse/image",
                    data: {apikey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", url: s},
                    //method: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    processData: false,
                    type: 'GET',
                    crossDomain: true,
                    xhrFields: {
                        // The 'xhrFields' property sets additional fields on the XMLHttpRequest.
                        // This can be used to set the 'withCredentials' property.
                        // Set the value to 'true' if you'd like to pass cookies to the server.
                        // If this is enabled, your server must respond with the header
                        // 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true'.
                        withCredentials: true
                    },
                    headers: {
                        // Set any custom headers here.
                        // If you set any non-simple headers, your server must include these
                        // headers in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' response header.
                    },
                    success: function(ocrParsedResult, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        //Get the parsed results, exit code and error message and details
                        var parsedResults = ocrParsedResult["ParsedResults"];
                        var ocrExitCode = ocrParsedResult["OCRExitCode"];
                        var isErroredOnProcessing = ocrParsedResult["IsErroredOnProcessing"];
                        var errorMessage = ocrParsedResult["ErrorMessage"];
                        var errorDetails = ocrParsedResult["ErrorDetails"];

                        var processingTimeInMilliseconds = ocrParsedResult["ProcessingTimeInMilliseconds"];

                        //If we have got parsed results, then loop over the results to do something
                        if (parsedResults!= null) {
                            //Loop through the parsed results
                            $.each(parsedResults, function (index, value) {
                                var exitCode = value["FileParseExitCode"];
                                var parsedText = value["ParsedText"];
                                var errorMessage = value["ParsedTextFileName"];
                                var errorDetails = value["ErrorDetails"];

                                var textOverlay = value["TextOverlay"];

                                var pageText = '';
                                switch (+exitCode) {
                                    case 1: 
                                        pageText = parsedText;
                                        break;
                                    case 0:
                                    case -10:
                                    case -20:
                                    case -30:
                                    case -99:
                                    default: 
                                        pageText += "Error: " + errorMessage;
                                        break;
                                }

                                console.log(parsedText);


                                var bazExtract = extractEmails1(parsedText);
                                if(bazExtract !== null) {
                                    extractEmails2(bazExtract);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                });
            });
            //console.log(imgSrcArr);
        });
```

A note: Other sections of the content script code are running as expected but there's **no Server response** (in the developer console) to the Ajax request.

If this is a CORS issue, is there a workaround for this kind of an error? I tried a handful of answers to similar questions on SO but I'm unable to move forward with any of those.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery .ajax() POST Request throws 405 (Method Not Allowed) on RESTful WCF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333013/jquery-ajax-post-request-throws-405-method-not-allowed-on-restful-wcf)

Comment: you can't use an object as the `data:` parameter if you use `contentType: "application/json"` and `processData: false`. The `processData` option says not to convert the object to a string, and `$.ajax` doesn't know how to send JSON.

Comment: You should only use `processData: false` if you do `data: formData`. And then you should use `contentType: 'multipart/form-data'`.

Comment: @Barmar Hey I changed `contentType` to `'multipart/form-data'` and `data` to `formData` and `type` to `POST` and now I see no error or any server response in the console. I should at least be able to see `console.log(parsedText)`. Why is it so?

Comment: Do you see the request and response in the Network tab of the console?

Comment: @Barmar I'm not that familiar with the Network tab. However, in the XHR part of the Network tab I see only _1 red line_ with _Initiator_ as _VM20787:4_. Does it have anything to do with my code?

Comment: I don't think so. Names like that come from code that's created on the fly with `eval()`.

Comment: Your code is running when the page is first loaded. Make sure you have the Network tab open before you reload the page, otherwise it won't capture this.

Comment: @Barmar Did that but no noticeable changes :(. Network tab shows only `DOMContentLoaded: 11.53s` and `Load: 29.66s`.

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside the `.each()` function to make sure it's running.

Comment: @Barmar You mean the **second** occurrence of `.each()` right? Can you suggest a suitable line that I can add 'cause `console.log` is not showing anything.

Comment: No, I mean the first occurrence. If you're not seeing anything in the Network tab, then it means none of the `$.ajax` calls are being done. Put the breakpoint on the `$.ajax` line.

Comment: @Barmar I typed `debugger;` right before the occurrence of `$.ajax()` and when I reload the page the Developer Tools takes me to the `debugger;` line. How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Why do you do that instead of setting the breakpoint in the source viewer? Just click on a line to add or remove a breakpoint. Anyway, now you can open the Network tab to make sure it's recording AJAX request, then go back to the Source tab and click the arrow button to continue.

Answer (score 1):

The title "Post Parameters" in the [documentation](https://ocr.space/OCRAPI) of the API suggests that you should do a POST, not a GET. That is, use: `type: POST`

Comment: And get rid of the `contentType` and `processData` options as well.

Comment: @Barmar When I remove `contentType` and `processData` keeping `type` is 'POST' I'm getting `jQuery.Deferred exception: Illegal invocation TypeError: Illegal invocation` which points to `$.ajax` line and `$('img')` line. FYI I changed `$('img')` to `$('img[src *= "mail"]')` and that shouldn't affect my existing code right?

Comment: @SunandoSamaddar What do you have as the `data` option when you do that? Your comment above says you changed to `data: formData`, and in that case you DO need `processData: false`.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry about that. This time I'm doing `data: formData` and `processData: false` but again can't see the `console.log(parsedText)` output in the console.