# Send JSON POST request to external domain without having access to the server

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax, cross-domain

I'm trying to make a `POST` request in `JSON` to an external domain but I can't access the server's files to modify them.

When I do this request, I get the following error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://external.com. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://www.ownedwebsite.com' is therefore not
>   allowed access.

Where is the problem?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#submit").on('click', function(){
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://external.com',
                    type : "POST",
                    crossDomain: true,
                    dataType : 'json',
                    beforeSend: function (request)
                    {
                    //request.setRequestHeader("name", "value");
                    },
                    data : $("#formCart").serialize(),
                    success : function(result) {
                    alert('POST done.');
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
                        alert('POST failed.');
                    }
                })
            });
        });
```

**What could I do? All I need to do is to send this POST form data in JSON format.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery .ajax() POST Request throws 405 (Method Not Allowed) on RESTful WCF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333013/jquery-ajax-post-request-throws-405-method-not-allowed-on-restful-wcf)

Comment: call the provider of external.net and ask them to add you to their CORS header

Comment: I need to perform the request without being abled to modify the CORS header etc.. so no, I can't "call the provider" @madalinivascu

Comment: does the provider allow you to use this resource, have you looked at their documentation?

Comment: The provider is just a test website of my company but I would like to do the request without enabling CORS header on server side due to other issues on the server site that make that not possible @madalinivascu

Comment: did you try jsonp ,is the test site capable of using jsonp ?

Comment: It should, the problem is that JSONP doesn't support a POST request

Comment: do you really need a post request? there is nothing you can do if you need a post request, except for modifying the test site

Comment: The post request is needed. There isn't an alternative way at all?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to get the `json` data from `twitter` you have to register for the `api` key, that means they are ready to serve with `json`, similar approaches applies with other sites.

if you simply want to grab the page then you could do it with `heroku api`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      var text = 'https://login.yahoo.com/';
      $.ajaxPrefilter( function (options) {
        if (options.crossDomain && jQuery.support.cors) {
          var http = (window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'http:' : 'https:');
          options.url = http + '//cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + options.url;
          //options.url = "http://cors.corsproxy.io/url=" + options.url;
        }
      });

      $.get(
          'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Alva_Edison_Memorial_Tower_and_Museum',
          function (response) {

          var res = response;
           $('#yahoo').append(res);


      });

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="yahoo"></div>
```

Comment: I need to send a POST request to it, not just get the page.

Comment: register for api key so that they will set the header to `allow your site`

Comment: otherwise use 'cURL`  with this you can login into other website it is an example of  `POST`

Comment: So I register to the api and make the call to this link and it will work as a mirror site of the external site I wanna query but while allowing me to create a CORS request? @EaBangalore