# Ajax: How to get request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, http

```
<p><input type="button" id="ajax" value="click here!"/><br/>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
      $('#ajax').click(
          function () {
              $.ajax({
                  type: 'get',
                  url: 'https://example.com',
                  success: function (data) {
                      alert("OKAY");
                  },
                  error: function (data) {
                      alert("NG");
                  }
              });
          });
  });
```

I want to GET request using Ajax in Rails but sent options request.

This is an error shown console log

`OPTIONS https://example.com 405 (Method Not Allowed)`

Comment: Because you are attempting to make a cross-domain request [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333013/jquery-ajax-post-request-throws-405-method-not-allowed-on-restful-wcf#17333053) it might help you

Comment: Try sending your AJAX request to a URL that's intended to accept AJAX requests. `http[s]://example.com` is not.